# Probability question on mutual exclusiveness

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Okay, it's like this:

Let A, B and C be events such that P[A|C] = 0.05 and P[B|C] = 0.05.

I was just wondering, should the events A and B be looked at as mutually exclusive, as in only one or the other could happen? In the back of my book they calculated P[A U B|C] as:

P[A|C] + P[B|C]. I don't really understand the justification. I mean, who's to say A and B can't happen at the same time?

EDIT:

Let A, B and C be events such that P[A|C] = 0.05 and P[B|C] = 0.05. Which of the following statements is true.

A) P[A n B|c] = (0.05)^2

B) P[A' n B'|C] >= .90

C) P[A U B|C] <= 0.05.

D) P[A U B|C'] >= 1 - (0.05)^2

E) P[A U B|C'] >= .10

Answer (score 0):

You're quite right, unless the book supplied additional information. In fact A and B could be the very same event.

Comment: Imma type the whole question from the text book. Maybe there is some other stuff I'm missing and not seeing in the whole question

Answer (score 0):

Definition of two events being mutually exclusive:
$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) +P(B)
$$
i.e., the event $P(A \cap B)=0$. If in your case $P(A \cup B|C) = 0.1$ then yes, $P(A|C)$ and $P(B|C)$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think in this case that's the cart before the horse, isn't it? Yes, the events should be considered mutually exclusive *given* that the sum of the conditional probabilities is 0.1. But that information is in the back of the book--that is, an answer supplied for a problem, rather than something given to the student as up-front information about A and B.

Comment: Exactly what Stumpy said. The problem doesn't specify that the union of A|C and B|C equals 0.1.

Comment: Then I totally miss what the OP wants. If the probability of the union of the events is calculated as above, then the events are mutually exclusive as only one of them can happen.